# I have created a macro using the if function but it doesn't seem to work. What am I misisng?

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro to show the following:

`If (I3<>0,I3*G3,H3*G3)` and this repeats itself for cell `N3, R3, V3, Z3` etc.

```
Option Explicit 
Sub Eg() 
    Range("J3, N3,R3, V3,Z3,AD3,AH3,AL3,AP3,AT3,Ax3,BB3,XF3,BJ3").Formula = "=IF(RC[-1]<>0,RC[-1]*RC[-3],RC[-2]*RC[-3])" 
End Sub
```

However this doesn't seem to work.
Let me explain a bit more how this should work:

This report needs to be downloaded from an application.
The macro needs to be attached to this report so that when I download the report the macro automatically runs this formula in the appropriate columns.

Also I'll have to populate the spreadsheet for all the rows with this formula.

The columns where the formula should sit are not blank but this needs to be catered for in the report automatically once the macro is run.

What am I missing here?

Comment: ... I'm not sure I understand your question... The formula itself (the macro you provided) works just fine... Can you explain more of what you're looking for help with...

Comment: so what is you question, what are you questions really?

Comment: Wouldn't work in Excel 2003 or earlier as the range XF3 wouldn't exist (the highest available column is IV in Excel 2003). Doubt this is the issue though

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Range.Formula = formulaAsString`, and the range refers to multiple cells, you specify the exact formula string as required by (only) the first cell in the range, while appropriately using relative vs. absolute cell references because the assignment to multiple (succeeding) cells will occur as if you were pasting the first cell in the range into the others, exactly as if you'd done a copy & paste without VBA -- you use absolute addressing A1 vs. A$1 vs. $A$1 vs. $A1 etc...  as desired to achieve the right alteration of the formula for the succeeding cells.

For example,

```
Range ("A1, C1, E1").Formula = "=A2+$A2"
```

will have the same result as

```
Range ( "A1" ).Formula = "=A2+$A2"
Range ( "C1" ).Formula = "=C2+$A2"
Range ( "E1" ).Formula = "=E2+$A2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up `.Formula` with `.FormulaR1C1`! Your string is R1C1 style, but you assign it to the A1 style formula.

Therefore, simply, change it to:

```
Range("J3, N3,R3, V3,Z3,AD3,AH3,AL3,AP3,AT3,Ax3,BB3,XF3,BJ3").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]<>0,RC[-1]*RC[-3],RC[-2]*RC[-3])"
```

or

```
Range("J3, N3,R3, V3,Z3,AD3,AH3,AL3,AP3,AT3,Ax3,BB3,XF3,BJ3").Formula = _
    "=IF(I3<>0,I3*G3,H3*G3)"
```

As Erik points out in his answer, also the later will work and adjust the formula for each cell in the same way (which is not necessary in R1C1 as the formula stays the same anyway...)